# Indirect duplication of a foreign key?

Tags: sql, database-design, oracle-sqldeveloper, rdbms

Suppose, I have three tables named Table user, team, task

| user |
| --- |
| user_id |
| team_id |

| team |
| --- |
| team_id |

| task |
| --- |
| task_id |
| user_id |
| team_id |

where the User table references team_id then a task table references the user_id and team_id. It sorts of create an indirect duplication of team_id because it was already referenced by user_id.

1. Is there a name for this?
2. Is this bad practice? (I have an inkling I should not do this)
3. Possible workarounds?

Thank you!

Comment: Can a user only belong to one team? If not, having say `team`, `user` and `team_user` tables might make sense. If a task can be allocated to both a team and a member of that team then having both of those in the task table doesn't seem unreasonable?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, the relationship is one(team) to many(user) for user and team then one(user) to many(task) and one(team) to many(task). Sorry if my reply is a bit verbose, I am still not well-versed with rdbms

Answer (score 0):

well it depends :

- Could a task be assigned to a team and someone from another team do it?
  if yes then team_ id should be referenced to team table
- Could a user id be repeated inside each team ?
  if yes then you need a combined fk of (user_id,team_id) referenced user( yuser_id, team_id) , here no link to team table.
- if the answer is no to above questions, then team_id is redundant and cause data inconsistency

Comment: 1. No, only one team can do a specific task.
2. No, one user can only have one team while the team can have many users
3. Should I just use nested join to select the team_id via user_id? 

Thank you for answering! :)